# Facebook PHP SDK 5: Extending classes

Tags: php, facebook, class, facebook-php-sdk

I'm newbie with classes (worse with namespaces, etc.) so I know must create the FacebookMyClass.php class where the main classes are (`autoload.php`, `Facebook.php`, `FacebookApp.php`, etc.), then my prototype:

```
<?php
// I guess
namespace Facebook;

// Do I must 'use' or extending other class(es)?
// use ;

class FacebookMyClass extends Facebook {

   // Do I have to "re-declare" parent's vars?
  private $my_private_var;
  public $my_public_var;
  private $access_token;

  // The main thing, I think, is how class is constructed

  // public function __construct(array $config = []) {
  public function __construct($id, $secret) {
    // This will work? Need parameters?
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function accessParentProtectedVars($idfanpage) {
    // How can I call/link to Facebook object/request/response?
    $object = $this->get('/' . $idfanpage . '/albums?fields=name,id', $this->access_token);
  }

  private function getTokens($params = []) {
    // code...
    $this->access_token = '...';
  }

}
?>
```

The question is: How can I extend Facebook\Facebook class(es)?

Comment: Why don't you use the FacebookResponses getBody() method? It returns the body property. 

`$body = $datos->getBody();`

Comment: @lordthorzonus You made my week! Although it doesn't answer my question about extending classes it resolves a big problem for me, Facebook documentation doesn't (I wish could be like CodeIgniter user guide).

Comment: Hope the answer below give you the explanation you're looking for.  lordthorzonus is correct though, always better to use the existing methods of a class if possible and only extend or implement when customization beyond what's available is necessary.

Comment: I think the question is wrong. You needed to get the Facebook response's body. @lordthorzonus told you how to get it. Now class inheritance is completely another matter. The example Sean provided is good but not related to Facebook. Now, just to add something else useful for you, the new documentation is very precise and easy to read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0. You should try to read documentation only there because they update it regularly and other tutorials may be outdated.

Comment: @DavidVartanian The question is right, is at the end: __The question is: How can I extend Facebook\Facebook class(es)?__ I think the question title is right too.

Comment: Regarding the text of your question you didn't want to extend the Facebook class. Instead you just wanted to get data from a facebook request. So please fix your question, title or body. Otherwise it will be useless for other users.

Comment: Ok ok @DavidVartanian just removed the problem explanation that take me to extend Facebook classes. By the way, the "new" documentation is not precise neither updated, can you tell me where is the `execute()` method that is mentioned everywhere into the Graph API documentation (like [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/album)) except into the provided SDK?

Comment: When I said "they update regularly" I meant the SDK. If you find some old tutorial on google probably you won't find the code that you expect. Now, the execute method should be in the FacebookRequest class. BUT, I've just checked it out and that method exists only on v4.0!! https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php. Now also the official documentation is out of date!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A namespace represents where a class or group of classes lives within a given project.

Extending a class means inheriting (gaining access to) its methods within the scope of your class.

So as an example, and keep in mind you may need to tweak this:

```
<?php
// Imports the class Facebook from the Facebook namespace eg /Facebook/Facebook.php
use Facebook\Facebook;

class MyFacebookExtension extends Facebook {

    function __construct(array $config = []) {
        // The base class requires an array parameter, so we accept that and forward it, and then call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    // .. whatever methods you want to add .. You can also now access facebook() methods like $this->getclient() etc within this class.
}
```